# Angular 5+ Constructor fields injector error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

So I'm not injecting a service simply trying to init some fields with a constructor like so.

```
  constructor(private wheels : number, private model : string, private automatic : boolean, private colour : string, private engine : string, private seats :number) { 
    this.wheels = wheels;
    this.model = model;
    this.automatic = automatic;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.engine = engine;
    this.seats = seats;
  }
```

I've tried it without the this.x=x now if I create a new object and then console.log the object it has all the inited values, but the project wont load & gives me this error message.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Module1AComponent -> Number]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Module1AComponent -> Number]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Number!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1034)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1271)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1216)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1271)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1216)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8161)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:8849)
    at resolveDep (core.js:9214)
```

Very frustrating as I can't seem to find an awful lot with regards to injection issues around fields, only in regards to services.

Comment: from what I can tell, what you're trying to inject is more suited to @Input than constructor injection when dealing with components.

Comment: Do you have the @Injectable decorator on this class?

Comment: Where are this constructor from? If its a component, you can't do that. you have to use @Input(), you cant provide parameters to constructor in component

Comment: Ok cheers it is indeed a component, I've been following a relatively old tutorial so I imagine that's the cause of the issue, I shall look into the @input fields

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you're passing parameters to Angular's Component class, so that its instance can be created `new`ed up. But as soon as you declared it as angular `@Component`. At the time of execution angular framework hijacks the class `constructor`, and started evaluating each parameter of `constructor` and check each parameter inside `Dependency Injection`. Basically it does pass each parameter's type as a `token` to Dependency Injection System. And extract the value map to that `token` based on `provider` register for that token inside `providers` array of `@NgModule`

Suppose you have written below class where constructor has `test` parameter of type `number`. At the time of Component execution Angular DI system will tries to find instance of `number` provider (ensuring singleton instance, depends on Injector hierarchy) and then serve that instance.

```
constructor(private test: number)
```

is also shorthand of

```
constructor(@Inject(number) private test)
```

Though I'd not recommend to allow to create Angular component class instance manually like the way you're thinking to do it. I'd not say it will not work, but its not good practice. Although the workaround to make it working would be using `@Optional()` decorator before theses parameters. [**`@Optional`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) will basically return the `null` value if value doesn't found inside `Dependency Injector` container of application context.

```
constructor(
    @Optional() private wheels : number,
    @Optional() private model : string,
    @Optional() private automatic : boolean,
    @Optional() private colour : string,
    @Optional() private engine : string,
    @Optional() private seats :number
) {
}
```

Comment: Okay so following this what I've done is create a service that creates the object fields for lets say my car object and then instantiated that within the component constructor and built my car objects that way, which works like a charm would this be an acceptable way/good practice to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor() function is expecting a provider object as a parameter, since "string" or "number" are types angular generates an error, if you just want to initialize some values you have to change your code to something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-main',
  templateUrl: './nav-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-main.component.css']
})
export class NavMainComponent implements OnInit {

  private wheels : number;
  private model : string;
  private automatic : boolean;
  private colour : string;
  private engine : string; 
  private seats :number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.wheels = 4;
    this.model = 'Model X';
    this.automatic = false;
    this.colour = 'Black';
    this.engine = 'Engine Y'; 
    this.seats = 5;
  }
}
```